# Navigation that Runs Above and Below Header Image

Tags: theme-twenty-eleven, menus

Is there a way to have a navigation div(s) on the Twentyeleven theme or similar themes that runs over the header image and finishes below the header image?

Basically so overflow runs below the image.

Here's an example:

[Link to Website](http://www.dillardandcompany.com/)

Comment: Quite simply, use two menus.

Comment: does not look like 'overflow' - as @sneek already said: two menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sneek's comment is your best bet. Otherwise, if you're bent on splitting one menu, you have three choices:

1. Use PHP to intercept the menu code and split it up before it gets output. This would work great in many regards, but it wouldn't be knowledgeable as to where the "break" occurs, so you'd need to do it by some other factor like # of characters
2. Use javascript to dynamically split up the menu. Because you can find elements' widths, you could find the "break" and split it at that location exactly.
3. Use some crafty CSS to reposition the latter elements. It would be hard to make this flexible, and you would not be able to locate the "break" as with #1. Essentially, you could only handle specific elements.

Comment: What's the best way to do this still using the appearance>menu option?

Comment: All three options refer to still using the appearance>menu option. If it were me, I would probably go with #1 or #2 depending on my exact needs. #1 will be more reliable since it won't require JS, but #2 will be more flexible with changing nav content.